# Barcode to webform, webform prefilled depending on barcode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, webforms, barcode

I need to generate multiple barcodes which on reading will send the user to a landing page with a webform. On submit the info is sent to an email account.

**I.e> **

The user scanned Barcode 1  > info sent to email : barcode 1 ID + info filled in the form.

The user scanned Barcode 2  > info sent to email : barcode 1 ID + info filled in the form.

**The Problem:** how to know which of the barcodes was used if they are using the same landing page?

All your help will be most appreciated.

I'm aiming to use reatc and email JS to handle the form. Other wise MS Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you have to store a map that maps the user with barcodes scanned by him. This can be achieved via -

- Store barcodes in the local storage and send an email accordingly. Also implement a timeout to discard the stored data (to mark it as stale)
- You may move email-sending logic to the backend and maintain a session based on a unique ID

Comment: thanks! I'll be digging in options!